# What is the ".containers" list on a bar chart and where is the documentation on it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, containers, seaborn

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

ax = sns.countplot(my_data, x="some_feature",stat="percent")
ax.bar_label(container=ax.containers[0],label_type="center") # <- this line
```

I am having trouble understanding where the `ax.containers[0]` object comes from. I've been looking through Matplotlib documentation and cannot find any reference to `.containers` object and how that's the convention used to access the bar container object. I see there is documentation on `matplotlib.container` but can someone explain why `.containers` is used in place of `.container`?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a matplotlib `Axes` object it is initialized with the `containers` attribute being an empty list (it's not a `container` object, it is literally just a list). When you create a bar plot, matplotlib adds the `BarContainer` to the `.containers` list.

```py
import matplolib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
print(ax.containers)       # []
print(type(ax.containers)) # list
ax.bar(range(4), range(4))
print(ax.containers)       # [<BarContainer object of 4 artists>]
```

Looking at the `matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar` source code, we see [these lines](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/eb02b108ea181930ab37717c75e07ba792e01f1d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2563-L2566):

```py
bar_container = BarContainer(patches, errorbar, datavalues=datavalues,
                             orientation=orientation,
                             label=bar_container_label)
self.add_container(bar_container)
```

(Here, `self` is the `Axes` object.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and pointing out where and when the containers attribute comes into play. It seems like this attribute is missing from the Matplotlib API Reference. Thanks for pointing me to the Source Code.

Comment: Well, it is some "internal kitchen" of matplotlib. Adding everything to the official documentation would make it unwieldly. So, adding these labels in the case of a `sns.countplot` is something that isn't immediately supported, only via touching the internal structure (which can change in new versions). In that way, StackOverflow forms part of the unofficial documentation.

Comment: @ogplant If this answers your question then you can accept it by clicking the gray check next to it. You will also get some reputation for accepting an answer.